# Effective way to check whether particular data exist in each row and column or not?

Tags: sql, oracle

1) I want to pick row which contain data x in below table

2) I want to pick column which contain data x in below table

xtable

```
 ID C1 C2 C3 C4
--- -- -- --- --
  1 A  -  -   -
  2 -  A  -   -
  3 A  -  A   -
  4 -  A  -   -
  5 -  -  -   -
```

Solution i tried

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN exists (SELECT 1 FROM xtable WHERE C1 = 'A') THEN ROWNUM
         WHEN exists (SELECT 1 FROM xtable WHERE C2 = 'A') THEN ROWNUM
         WHEN exists (SELECT 1 FROM xtable WHERE C3 = 'A') THEN ROWNUM
         WHEN exists (SELECT 1 FROM xtable WHERE C4 = 'A') THEN ROWNUM
         ELSE 0
         END "Exist"
    FROM xtable;
```

But i wont work

Give some effective solution for above problem

Comment: If A values are from countable set, consider an opposite mapping, where A value is a key and column and row pairs are multiple mapped values

Comment: @NaveenM . . . I am unclear what you want as a result set.

Comment: Does `A` mean a fixed certain data exactly 'A' as a capital letter, or any non-null data(even a word or a sentence) occupying that coordinate while the other positions are completely null?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan  `A` is a NOT NULL value

Comment: well, it's just a fixed(constant) literal namely the capital letter 'A', what about the others ..? are they null ..?

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID C1  C2  C3  C4
---------- --- --- --- ---
         1 A
         2     A
         3 A       A
         4     A
         5
```

Rows that contain 'A':

```
SQL> select id
  2  from test
  3  where c1 = 'A' or c2 = 'A' or c3 = 'A' or c4 = 'A';

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4

SQL>
```

Columns that contain 'A':

```
SQL> select
  2    case when sum(case when c1 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'yes' else 'no' end c1,
  3    case when sum(case when c2 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'yes' else 'no' end c2,
  4    case when sum(case when c3 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'yes' else 'no' end c3,
  5    case when sum(case when c4 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'yes' else 'no' end c4
  6  from test;

C1  C2  C3  C4
--- --- --- ---
yes yes yes no

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to unpivot and select?

```
select t.*
from ((select id, c1 as c, 'c1' as which from t
      ) union all
      (select id, c2, 'c2' as which from t
      ) union all
      (select id, c3, 'c3' as which from t
      ) union all
      (select id, c4, 'c4' as which from t
      ) union all
      (select id, c5, 'c5' as which from t
      ) 
     ) t
where c = 'A'
```

Comment: Actually i need output like what @Littlefoot given above

Comment: @NaveenM . . . Then you should probably accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

A query for both 1 & 2.

```
SELECT ID
, CASE WHEN C1=X.C THEN 'yes' WHEN C1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'no' END AS C1
, CASE WHEN C2=X.C THEN 'yes' WHEN C2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'no' END AS C2
, CASE WHEN C3=X.C THEN 'yes' WHEN C3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'no' END AS C3
, CASE WHEN C4=X.C THEN 'yes' WHEN C4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'no' END AS C4
FROM XTABLE T
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'A' C FROM DUAL) X
WHERE X.C IN (C1,C2,C3,C4)
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b76cba1f89b29c7c39d9a351c49eb153)*

**Example of result:**

> ```
> ID | C1   | C2   | C3   | C4  
> -: | :--- | :--- | :--- | :---
>  1 | yes  | null | null | null
>  2 | null | yes  | null | no  
>  3 | yes  | null | yes  | null
>  4 | null | null | null | yes
> ```

Comment: Nice...! and Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for whether at least one non-null value exists in the rows or columns of your table, then one option to use would be combinations of `decode()`, `sign()` and `nvl2()` functions together ;

For rows :

```
SELECT ID, 
       decode( sign( nvl2(C1,1,0)+nvl2(C2,1,0)+nvl2(C3,1,0)+nvl2(C4,1,0) ), 1, 'yes','no') 
   as "Exists"  
  FROM xtable
```

For columns :

```
SELECT decode( sign(sum( nvl2(C1,1,0) )), 1, 'yes','no') as "Exists in C1",
       decode( sign(sum( nvl2(C2,1,0) )), 1, 'yes','no') as "Exists in C2",
       decode( sign(sum( nvl2(C3,1,0) )), 1, 'yes','no') as "Exists in C3",
       decode( sign(sum( nvl2(C4,1,0) )), 1, 'yes','no') as "Exists in C4"
  FROM xtable
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4e4898be16d601df5a5b94d7afa5cc12)</kbd>

If you're looking for exact matching for the letter `'A'`, then consider using :

```
SELECT ID, 
       decode( sign( decode(C1,'A',1,0)+
                     decode(C2,'A',1,0)+
                     decode(C3,'A',1,0)+
                     decode(C4,'A',1,0) ), 1, 'yes','no') as "Exists"  
  FROM xtable
```

**and**

```
SELECT decode( sign(sum( decode(C1,'A',1,0) )), 1, 'yes','no') as "Exists in C1",
       decode( sign(sum( decode(C2,'A',1,0) )), 1, 'yes','no') as "Exists in C2",
       decode( sign(sum( decode(C3,'A',1,0) )), 1, 'yes','no') as "Exists in C3",
       decode( sign(sum( decode(C4,'A',1,0) )), 1, 'yes','no') as "Exists in C4"
  FROM xtable
```

e.g.replace `nvl2(Cn,1,0)` expressions with `decode(Cn,'A',1,0)`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2e1347b86ce862193692606b1c85a967)</kbd>